# How to support artifact binding in itfoxtec?

Tags: c#, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are using ITFoxTec library for saml auhentication. Currently we are supporting two types binging.
Http-Redirect
Http-Post
Now we want to extend it to artifact binding.  Is it supported in this library. If u have some reference please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Artifact binding is not supported in the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library I am afraid.

But I have some code to share. The ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 libraries predecessor is the ITfoxtec.Saml2 library. [Snede](https://github.com/Snede) has extended the old ITfoxtec.Saml2 library with support for the Artifact binding and [shared the code](https://github.com/Snede/ITfoxtec.SAML2/commit/396a226aabeefe022d8bb2ee9d05a3aaceb8d376). As of my knowledge this code is tested with one or two IdPs and should work.

There is not that match different between the the old and new library. Therefore, I think it should be fairly easy to port the code to the new ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library.

If you do port the code please share e.g. on StackOverflow or GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Anders, Will share with you

Comment: Was there any progress on this? Has the artifact code been shared; has it been integrated? The link to the Snede repo is dead, it seems the fork has been removed. I found this: https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/issues/53, does not sound like it has been done or is about to be done. Would be so great to have this...

Comment: There have not been any progress regarding artifact, I'm afraid.

Comment: (Update) Artifact Binding is now available on ITfoxtex.Identity.Saml2